# TypeScript - How to import module in other file

Tags: typescript, module

*name1.name2.name3*.ts file has one module

i.e.

```
/**
 * name1.name2.name3.ts
 */

 declare var PROCESS_ENGINE_BASEURL;
declare var CONST_HTTP_GET;

export module Name1.Name2 {

    export class Name3 {
       ...... 
       ......
      }
}
```

and in other file *name1.name2.name5.name6.name7*.ts

how can i import module Name1.Name2 from file *name1.name2.name3*.ts

both file are in same directory

I tried following

```
/**
 * name1.name2.name5.name6.name7.ts
 */

    import abc = require("name1.name2.name3"); failed

    import abc = require("name1.name2"); failed

    import abc = require("Name1.Name2"); failed

    import * as abc from "name1.name2.name3"; failed

    import * as abc from "name1.name2"; failed

    import * as abc from "Name1.Name2"; failed
```

Comment: Name3 is the only class in the module Name1.Name2?

Comment: showing error "Can't find module '.....' "

Comment: @suraj yes, Name3 is only class in Name1.Name2 for now

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to [stop mixing internal and external modules](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/).

Therefore:

1. Remove `export module ...` from Name3.ts
2. Organize your code using file system: each module - its own file. Group modules in folders. In your case you will most likely end up with the following structure: `Name1 / Name2 / Name3.ts`, where `Name1` and `Name2` are folders.

After that - import `Name3` any way you prefer, for example to import it from file (module) that is located in the same folder as `Name1`:

```
import {Name3} from './Name1/Name2/Name3';
```